# Deleting table row saved in NSUserDefualt iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

In my application I am giving name to my PDF file with the help of AlertView textfield. The names are saving in Array of table list as well as NSUserDefault to access at any time. Now when I am deleting the single row of table the whole list of NSUserDefault is getting disappeared. Could you please suggest some trick over here in my code. Thanks in advance.

**Updated code(viewDidLoad)** with comments

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
  NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 //Checking previous NSUserDefault. Here I need trick to open the previous updated     NSUserDefault

 if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] != nil)
 {
 self.tablePdfListArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

 }

 }
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
 if(!self. tablePdfListArray)
    {

        self.tablePdfListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

//the below if condition will not allow repeatative string array in tableList and textfield lenth.

    if ([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] != 0 && ![self.tablePdfListArray containsObject:self.myPDFName])
    {

        [self.tablePdfListArray insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text] atIndex:0];

        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

        [self.pdfListnameTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        //adding table Array in NSUserDefaults

        NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:self.tablePdfListArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [defaults synchronize];


    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Deleting single table row. The NSUserDefault should be updated here.

   // NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
   // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    [pdfListnameTable beginUpdates];
    [pdfListnameTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [pdfListnameTable deleteSections:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [pdfListnameTable endUpdates];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are removing all defaults when using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

Just remove this line of code

Comment: still all the table array getting deleted instead of only selected row .

Comment: Did you check if the self.tablePdfListArray contains correct objects? Just print out them all and see.

Comment: Yes added key and deleted key is similar but when I print in viewDidLoad code the key [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.",[self.tablePdfListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] is showing nil value. Can you check my updated code... I think key should be unique to display remaining NSUserDefault. How it will be fit in my code.

Comment: Tell me, what do you want to do? Why are you storing values in user defaults? May be you need just use a property (NSMutableDictionary for example) for that?

Comment: Actually table list are name of PDF files. I am opening PDF files saved in NSDocument. So this PDF name list should be stored to open at any time. How it would go with NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Or use NSMutableArray. Declare array in interface. Then when adding file - just [array addObject:@"name of file"]; Then when you need to remove object: [array removeObject:@"name of file"];

Comment: @nerowolfe: where you trying to log the `NSUserDefaults` content to get nil? if you build and run again in xcode, each time the `NSUserdefaults` will be reinitialized and so it will be empty.